# AdWhirl in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, adwhirl

I see these messages in the console when implementing AdWhirl in my project and run the app in the Simulator:

```
2011-07-14 14:24:28.615 TNAdWhirl[10927:207] AdWhirlConfig: HTTP 503, cancelling http://mob.adwhirl.com/getInfo.php?appid=577208a7f7314ea5adbea44d19b863f0&appver=300&client=1
2011-07-14 14:24:28.617 TNAdWhirl[10927:207] Another fetch is in progress, wait until finished.
2011-07-14 14:24:28.618 TNAdWhirl[10927:207] Another fetch is in progress, wait until finished.
2011-07-14 14:24:28.713 TNAdWhirl[10927:207] AdWhirlConfig: HTTP 503, cancelling http://mob.adwhirl.com/getInfo.php?appid=577208a7f7314ea5adbea44d19b863f0&appver=300&client=1
2011-07-14 14:24:28.817 TNAdWhirl[10927:207] AdWhirlConfig: HTTP 503, cancelling http://mob.adwhirl.com/getInfo.php?appid=577208a7f7314ea5adbea44d19b863f0&appver=300&client=1
2011-07-14 14:24:28.818 TNAdWhirl[10927:207] Failed fetching AdWhirl config: Error Domain=com.adwhirl.sdk.ErrorDomain Code=11 "Config server did not return status 200" UserInfo=0x6553770 {NSLocalizedDescription=Config server did not return status 200}
```

I see no ads.
Do you know what happen, and how to fix it?

Comment: same here. it's the first time for me. no ads for all of my games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that AdWhirl is temporarily offline. It's probably maintenance, check back in a hour or so, that might fix it. If not, talk to adwhirl.